# Rally LookBack API with Release filter not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally, lookbackapi

Rally LookBack API with Release filter not working

Hello Friends, I need to add "Release filter" to the Defect Trends report at "https://github.com/RallyCommunity/DefectTrendApp/blob/master/deploy/App.html"

However due to some stranage reason. it does not fetches any results. I cant find anything release related to filter in the documentation as well.

It would be great, if any one will let me know if this is not supported or I am missing something.

I tried adding filters such as

```
releaseFilters = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.QueryFilter', {
                        property: 'Defect.Release.Name',
                          operator: '=',
                        value: '4.11'
                    });
```

Tried using the ObjectID as well. However no success.

Please help.

Comment: Please do let me know if the question is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 releaseFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.QueryFilter', {
        property: 'Release',
        operator: '=',
        value: 16995672374
      });
      return projectFilter.and(typeFilter.and(stateFilters)).and(releaseFilter);
```

Please make sure not to use quotes around the ObjectID. Also, Release.Name will not work since LBAPI does not access Release or Iteration Name.

Here is a full js file where I use `$in` operator to filter in items from multiple releases:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
    var releaseFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.QueryFilter', {
        property: 'Release',
        operator: '$in',
        value: [16995672374,15679194578,14299783630]
      });
        Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
                fetch    : ['_UnformattedID', 'Name','Release'],
        filters  : [releaseFilter],
                listeners: {
                    load: this._onDataLoaded,
                    scope: this
                }
                }).load({
                    params : {
                        compress : true,
                        removeUnauthorizedSnapshots : true
                    }
                });          
    },
     _onDataLoaded: function(store, data){
                var workItems = store.getRange();
                _.each(workItems, function(item){                                  
                    console.log(item.get('_UnformattedID') + ' ' + item.get('Name') + ' ' + item.get('Release'))
                });
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks...Yes, I know this works, but how can I have this working if mutiple selections are allowed. In that case we will have an array and the "in" with array does not returns any results

Comment: Hello Nick, if you can please let me know if we can check release ObjectID against multiple values.

Comment: I included a js file in the post above. It is using $in.